# Validation rule on null picklist case object not firing

Tags: validation-rule

I am trying to create validation rule, when closing the case if product type and component and subcomponent is empty to fill the values.

```
AND(
OR(
ISBLANK(TEXT(Product_Type__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Component__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Sub_Component__c))
),
ISBLANK(Account.Name) ,
ISPICKVAL( Status, "Closed"),
RecordType.Name = "Support Case")
```

I have given defalut value as None in picklist fields.

This doesnt detect the null value for picklist values, not able to figure out why. Can some one please help what I am doing wrong.

Comment: How are you sure the picklist are the issues? Have you tried removing them and testing to see if it triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be due to the way ISBLANK and ISNULL differs by definition ISBLANK determines if an expression has a value then returns TRUE if it does not contains a value, then this function returns FALSE. ISNULL determines if an expression is null (blank) then returns TRUE if it is. If the expression contains a value, then this function returns FALSE.
Did you try ISNULL in validation rule?

Comment: `ISBLANK` has the same functionality as `ISNULL`, but with the added supported for text fields plus it's recommended per [the docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) for new formulas